# Correct creation of a database TreeView in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

In Microsoft SQL Server I have table like this:

```
Article    Type1    Type2       Type3      Name             Cost
----------------------------------------------------------------
ABC.100    Part     From box    Null       Board            300
ABC.200    Part     From fence  From blue  Another board    200
ABC.098    Null     Null        From blue  Thing            120
ABC.001    Blank    From box    Null       Board1           -12
```

There are no relationships, all in a single table.

How to correctly set up the TreeView as such:

- Database

  - Type1

    - Type2

      - Type3

When, selecting any "type" display table with rows according to Type/1/2/3

Comment: Could you explain it better? You have a fixed tree definition on the left side of a panel i guess, and when the user clicks on Type1/2/3 you want to display what exactly on the right panel?  do you have already a viewmodel?

Comment: No. I have only the table. I need to create a TreeView (I have described it above). A panel is the second case. The panel display rows that satisfy the selected type and nesting. I have only that Model wich present from EF.

Comment: More explanation:
- it is possible fill TreeView from this table?
- do I need create a custom control or I can get well-written code?

Comment: Well, since the tree nodes are some of the columns of your table , and specifically "Database" Type1/2/3" i d rather build the Tree statically. That is, add a tree into your XAML and add your nodes one by one

Comment: This is one of the possible ways. Like this I was doing in WinForms.